# Call multiple async functions using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I have the following function that makes a call to the api

```
  useEffect(() => {
    loadMarkets();
  }, []);

  async function loadMarkets() {
    const marketInformation = await frService.getMarketInfo();
    addMarketInfo(marketInformation.response.data);
  }
```

I want to make a similar call to `loadBooks()`. If I don't mind which method comes first, would I be able to just call it like below or should I be wrapping this in 1 async function/wrap it in a Promise?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    loadMarkets();
    loadBooks();
  }, []);

  async function loadMarkets() {
    const marketInformation = await frService.getMarketInfo();
    addMarketInfo(marketInformation.response.data);
  }

  async function loadBooks() {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    loadMarkets();
    loadBooks();
```

because these function are prefixed with the `async` keyword, these are promise. loadBooks will be fired before loadMarkets finishes.

simple answer, yes you can do as you wrote, however I would try to catch the errors with something like

loadMarkets().catch(doSomethingIfThereIsAnError)

where `doSomethingIfThereIsAnError` would be a function that does som...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter which comes first since both of them are `async`. During the initial rendering of your component, `useEffect` will invoke both `async` functions. If you need to check which api endpoint gets called first and how much time it takes for the execution, you can open browser dev tools and check the network tab.